# GSA no returning Search Logs

Tags: google-search, google-search-appliance

While logging to Search Appliance I can see Reports tab with three links to:

- Serving Logs
- Search Reports
- Search Logs

In Serving Logs I can see users are submitting queries. When I go to either Reports of Logs for the same day I can't see any of the queries that users have asked.
Are there any restrictions what can be displayed in Serving Logs but cannot be dispalyed in Reports or Logs?

EDIT: If this is of any help, when I use google search using my_ip/search my queries are being displyed in Logs but still not in Reports

Answer (score 0):

When generating Search Logs and Search Reports, assure that you have selected the right collection to generate logs / reports from! You can find the right collection-name in the serving logs in the "Full query URI" string, it's the value of the site-parameter.

Comment: Thank for anwering. Even if I select all collections there is no results. It must be something else